# While loop causing asynchronous issues

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have the following code. I'm relativly new to protractor & JavaScript so apologies if this is a stupid question but I have done a lot of research with no luck. All I'm trying to do is select an option from a drop down until a certain button appears. All my code works but when I put it into a while loop it doesn't do anything. Can anyone explain why this is happening? I know it's something to do with the way it's asynchronous but I'm self thought and can't figure this one out. Thanks in advance.

```
 function selectProject(i){
            var selectSecondProject = element(by.id('translation-brief--select-project')).all(by.tagName('option')).get(i);
            selectSecondProject.click().then(function() {
                browser.sleep(2000);
            });
        };

    it('should select a different project from the drop down menu', function(){
        var loop = true;
        var i = 1;
        while(loop == true){
            selectProject(i).then(function(){
                browser.sleep(2000);
            });
                element(by.id('brief-button')).isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible) {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        loop = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        i++;
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: That while loop is going to lock the js up completely. None of the promises can resolve until the stack clears, which is impossible while the loop is running. And since no promise can resolve during that time, the `loop` variable will never be set to false (and thus you're now looping forever). You'll have to find another way to do what you're wanting here.

Answer (score 1):

The `sleep` function is executed asynchronously, so it's not really happening inside the timing of the loop. In fact, the loop should likely go on forever, never giving the `then` function, along with the `sleep`, a chance to ever execute.

The way to make a loop function asynchronously is to either use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to restart the loop. I can go into that in more detail if it isn't clear.

Update:

Here's a rough idea of what I'd suggest (I haven't actually tested this code, so beware. It's just a rough idea!):

```
it('should select a different project from the drop down menu', function(){
    var i = 1;
    function myLoop () {
        selectProject(i).then(function(){
            browser.sleep(2000);
            element(by.id('brief-button')).isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible) {
                if (!isVisible) {
                    i++;
                    setTimeout(myLoop);
                }
            });
        })
    }

    myLoop();
});
```

Comment: ya you're right the sleeps aren't being executed. If you could go into further detail it'd be really appreciated. I just find it extremely confusing the way everything works without the loop and breaks when there is a loop.

Comment: I'll add some more to my answer above so I have more code formatting available than I can do in a comment. :)

Comment: I got to test that code now. It works if the brief buttons appears first time, but if it's not there first time I get a failure saying element not visible, but it shouldn't be visible so not sure what I can do here, thank you anyway